# snap apps now won't start with "cannot perform readlinkat()" error

Tags: 18.04, snap, docker

I have at least spotify and docker installed via snap. Both of these fail with the same error message:

"cannot perform readlinkat() on the mount namespace file descriptor of the init process: Permission denied".

Some other snap apps work for me.

I am using 18.04 and have applied all updates.  Neither rebooting nor reinstalling fix the issue. And nor does reinstalling snap itself.

I am unsure as to how to go about fixing the issue.

Comment: What's the output of `snap version`? I think perhaps you're possibly running an unsupported kernel. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1709155

Comment: hello-world works.  In any case, snap was developed by Canonical which is the Ubuntu owner isn't it?

Comment: I have the same issue with telegram-desktop . Until recently it worked just fine.

Answer (score 10):

```
sudo snap refresh core --edge
```

Run the above command to update the snap core package.

For me after I updated my kernel to Linux 4.18 it did not work with the same error message but after running the above command all works fine.

You may need to reboot.