# Getting an error while installing snap packages. Cannot read device key pair

Tags: snap

Wondering why I'm unable to install snap packages, while in software center and using `sudo snap install ...`. It gives me an error and I'm unable to discern what's causing it nor am I able to find others with the same issue.

[image: software center error]

So when I try to install it using terminal, I get the full error:

```
~$ sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Download snap "pycharm-community" (103) from channel "stable" (cannot read device key pair: cannot find key pair)
```

This is happening with every package I attempt to install, I'm just showing PyCharm as an example. Any pointers or anyone having the same issue that's found a resolution?

## Update:

I have checked `/var/lib/snapd/device/private-keys-v1` and it contains nothing.

I also ran:

`sudo snap refresh core --edge`

And got this error:

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Download snap "core" (6990) from channel "edge" (cannot read device key pair: cannot find key pair)
```

I am unsure if I need to install from a repo or how to correctly install it.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling snapd? Run `sudo apt purge snapd; sudo apt install snapd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply purge as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035915/how-to-remove-snap-store-from-ubuntu/1035917#1035917) with

`sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd`

Then install

`sudo apt install snapd snapd-xdg-open`

Sources:

[How can I safely remove snap without breaking apparmor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120452/how-can-i-safely-remove-snap-without-breaking-apparmor?noredirect=1&lq=1)

https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-install-pycharm-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-and-18-04/

Comment: Damn!! I missed the bounty. I should have written my comment as an answer.

Comment: Doing this will of course remove all of your snap packages. I don't know why I even considered doing it. This answer is very dangerous. And why installing `snapd-xdg-open` instead of `snapd`?

Comment: @bomben To the best of my knowledge snapd-xdg-open is A D-Bus-activatable helper service allowing snaps to launch URLs on the host where its installed. If you actually parse the command provided you'll see it's installing snapd as well as snapd-xdg-open, not INSTEAD of.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check `/var/lib/snapd/device/private-keys-v1` directory.

In my case it was empty. I was unable to find the key generation command, so as a workaround I copied private key from that directory of another system and it worked.

However, I'm not sure it's the best possible solution. Try [snap apps now won't start with "cannot perform readlinkat()" error](https://askubuntu.com/q/1042270) answer before using the workaround. I wanted to test it, but I couldn't reproduce key absence again (by renaming `private-keys-v1` dir).