# How can I safely remove snap without breaking apparmor

Tags: snap, 18.10, apparmor

I'd like to remove Snap from my system entirely, but have a smallish problem:

1st, I removed all snap packages:

```
sudo snap remove $(snap list | tail -n +2 | cut -d" " -f1 | grep -v core | tr "/n" " ")
```

Then I removed snapd, and the gnome snap plugin

```
sudo apt remove -y snapd gnome-software-plugin-snap
```

The problem is that at reboot, Apparmor is looking for a profile for snap, and fails parsing snap configuration files:

```
Feb 21 21:40:47 dad apparmor[698]: AppArmor parser error for /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap-confine.core.5662 in /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap-confine.core.5662 at line 11: Could not open '/var/lib/snapd/apparmor/snap-confine'
```

which leaves me with a running system, and no apparmor!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The AppArmor profile is located in */etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine.real* file, which came from `snapd` package.

So you should use `apt purge` instead `apt remove` (see [`man apt`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/apt.8.html) for details):

```
sudo apt purge snapd
```

---

Small note: for me the snippet below looks better -

```
snap remove $(snap list | awk '{print $1}' | egrep -v "Name|core")
```

Comment: I ran with purge, and there's a line that prints specifically stating that it has removed the apparmor profiles!

Comment: That worked well.  I'm going to look at the difference between 'remove' and 'purge', but then I think I should find `sudo apt remove snap` and modify those answers

Comment: Great! The differences are indicated in `man apt`. It seems that [Dobey did this right](https://askubuntu.com/a/1035917/66509) :)

Comment: I thought about using ASK for the little code, but I saw the otherone a few days back, and it made me learn a bit more about the shell.

Comment: If you've already removed snapd, but still need to remove snapd leftovers, you can do so by performing 'sudo dpkg --purge snapd' which should remove the problematic AppArmor profile, as noted here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1773515/comments/8