# Ubuntu drains too much battery in my laptop

Tags: power-management, battery, 19.10

I switched from Windows to Ubuntu 3 months ago because of the degree I'm studying (CS) and didn't feel like doing my homework on a virtual machine because it wasn't really fast. However, my battery doesn't last for more than 2 hours, despite the fact that TLP is activated.

I've been considering switching to Mint but I've already gotten used to Ubuntu. Is there anything I could do to increase my battery's time of use while not charging it or should I switch to another distro which consumes less battery?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

```
top - 23:29:23 up 23 min,  1 user,  load average: 1,30, 1,35, 1,24
Tasks: 344 total,   2 running, 342 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  2,2 us,  1,0 sy,  0,0 ni, 96,1 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,7 si,  0,0 st
MiB Mem :  11852,5 total,   9008,7 free,    868,8 used,   1975,1 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2048,0 total,   2048,0 free,      0,0 used.  10567,6 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                             
12010 hector    20   0 2850020 221788  82876 S  10,7   1,8   0:04.66 gnome-shell                                                                                                                                         
11787 hector    20   0  281472  36024  23112 R   8,0   0,3   0:01.26 Xorg                                                                                                                                                
12812 hector    20   0  961324  48208  35252 S   6,7   0,4   0:00.55 gnome-terminal-                                                                                                                                     
  301 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   1,3   0,0   0:02.70 irq/83-SYNA2B4B                                                                                                                                     
11052 root      20   0       0      0      0 D   1,3   0,0   0:00.07 kworker/u24:3+events_unbound                                                                                                                        
12230 hector    20   0  369052  46648  27072 S   1,3   0,4   0:00.52 indicator-cpufr                                                                                                                                     
12867 hector    20   0   14716   4404   3368 R   1,3   0,0   0:00.05 top                                                                                                                                                 
    1 root      20   0  169032  12952   8012 S   0,0   0,1   0:03.29 systemd                                                                                                                                             
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                                                                                                                            
    3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 rcu_gp                                                                                                                                              
    4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 rcu_par_gp                                                                                                                                          
    6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H-kblockd                                                                                                                                
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.71 kworker/u24:0-events_power_efficient                                                                                                                
    9 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq                                                                                                                                        
   10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.02 ksoftirqd/0                                                                                                                                         
   11 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:01.05 rcu_sched                                                                                                                                           
   12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.01 migration/0                                                                                                                                         
   13 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 idle_inject/0                                                                                                                                       
   14 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 cpuhp/0                                                                                                                                             
   15 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 cpuhp/1                                                                                                                                             
   16 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 idle_inject/1                                                                                                                                       
   17 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.02 migration/1                                                                                                                                         
top - 23:29:57 up 23 min,  1 user,  load average: 0,94, 1,26, 1,21
Tasks: 341 total,   1 running, 340 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1,1 us,  0,3 sy,  0,0 ni, 98,4 id,  0,1 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,2 si,  0,0 st
MiB Mem :  11852,5 total,   9009,8 free,    843,2 used,   1999,5 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2048,0 total,   2048,0 free,      0,0 used.  10569,1 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                       
12010 hector    20   0 2848128 224820  84420 S   5,0   1,9   0:06.63 gnome-shell                                                                                                                                   
11787 hector    20   0  289984  44564  31652 S   2,3   0,4   0:02.79 Xorg                                                                                                                                          
12812 hector    20   0  963300  49732  35252 S   2,3   0,4   0:01.78 gnome-terminal-                                                                                                                               
  301 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   1,3   0,0   0:03.10 irq/83-SYNA2B4B                                                                                                                               
12120 hector    20   0  387204   8456   6988 S   1,0   0,1   0:00.13 ibus-daemon                                                                                                                                   
top - 23:30:00 up 24 min,  1 user,  load average: 0,94, 1,26, 1,21
Tasks: 341 total,   2 running, 339 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1,5 us,  0,4 sy,  0,0 ni, 98,1 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,1 si,  0,0 st
MiB Mem :  11852,5 total,   8956,1 free,    843,3 used,   2053,1 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2048,0 total,   2048,0 free,      0,0 used.  10515,5 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                             
12010 hector    20   0 2857888 233608  93184 S   8,7   1,9   0:06.84 gnome-shell                                                                                                                                         
11787 hector    20   0  283276  37724  24284 R   2,9   0,3   0:02.89 Xorg                                                                                                                                                
12812 hector    20   0  963300  49732  35252 S   1,9   0,4   0:01.84 gnome-terminal-                                                                                                                                     
  301 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   1,0   0,0   0:03.14 irq/83-SYNA2B4B                                                                                                                                     
  323 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   1,0   0,0   0:02.02 irq/128-i2c_hid                                                                                                                                     
11785 hector    20   0    9016   6332   3972 S   1,0   0,1   0:00.41 dbus-daemon                                                                                                                                         
12092 hector    20   0 2526096  29048  22044 S   1,0   0,2   0:00.40 cpufreq-service                                                                                                                                     
12133 hector    20   0  278752  30804  18256 S   1,0   0,3   0:01.51 ibus-extension-                                                                                                                                     
12867 hector    20   0   14716   4404   3368 R   1,0   0,0   0:00.21 top                                                                                                                                                 
    1 root      20   0  169032  12952   8012 S   0,0   0,1   0:03.46 systemd                                                                                                                                             
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                                                                                                                            
    3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 rcu_gp                                                                                                                                              
    4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 rcu_par_gp                                                                                                                                          
    6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H-kblockd                                                                                                                                
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.78 kworker/u24:0-i915                                                                                                                                  
    9 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq                                                                                                                                        
   10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.02 ksoftirqd/0                                                                                                                                         
   11 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:01.08 rcu_sched                                                                                                                                           
   12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.01 migration/0                                                                                                                                         
   13 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 idle_inject/0                                                                                                                                       
   14 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 cpuhp/0                                                                                                                                             
   15 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 cpuhp/1                                                                                                                                             
top - 23:30:12 up 24 min,  1 user,  load average: 1,02, 1,26, 1,22
Tasks: 342 total,   3 running, 339 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 15,8 us,  2,5 sy,  0,0 ni, 79,9 id,  0,8 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,9 si,  0,0 st
MiB Mem :  11852,5 total,   8914,1 free,    929,1 used,   2009,3 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2048,0 total,   2048,0 free,      0,0 used.  10474,7 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                       
 2499 root      20   0  360564  53432  14316 R  77,1   0,4   0:07.81 packagekitd                                                                                                                                   
13084 hector    20   0 1109492 122176  37864 R  35,5   1,0   0:02.70 gnome-software                                                                                                                                
 1277 root      20   0 2401688  30540  13608 S  12,3   0,3   0:03.34 snapd                                                                                                                                         
11787 hector    20   0  292052  45376  31936 S   4,0   0,4   0:03.83 Xorg                                                                                                                                          
12812 hector    20   0  963300  49992  35356 S   3,1   0,4   0:02.30 gnome-terminal-                                                                                                                               
  301 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0,6   0,0   0:03.23 irq/83-SYNA2B4B                                                                                                                               
  398 root      19  -1  190984  43232  41144 S   0,6   0,4   0:01.16 systemd-journal                                                                                                                               
13087 hector    20   0  422332  28540  19924 S   0,6   0,2   0:00.15 update-notifier                                                                                                                               
    1 root      20   0  169032  12952   8012 S   0,3   0,1   0:03.49 systemd                                                                                                                                       
  323 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0,3   0,0   0:02.07 irq/128-i2c_hid                                                                                                                               
 1251 message+  20   0    9908   6508   3852 S   0,3   0,1   0:03.52 dbus-daemon                                                                                                                                   
 1258 root      20   0  241172   7884   6780 S   0,3   0,1   0:00.24 accounts-daemon                                                                                                                               
 1375 root      20   0  244144  11008   7768 S   0,3   0,1   0:03.58 polkitd                                                                                                                                       
 2125 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0,3   0,0   0:00.48 kworker/u24:2-events_power_efficient                                                                                                          
11785 hector    20   0    9016   6332   3972 S   0,3   0,1   0:00.43 dbus-daemon                                                                                                                                   
12063 hector    20   0  317308   9032   8004 S   0,3   0,1   0:00.01 goa-identity-se                                                                                                                               
12092 hector    20   0 2534292  29244  22044 S   0,3   0,2   0:00.45 cpufreq-service                                                                                                                               
12867 hector    20   0   14716   4404   3368 R   0,3   0,0   0:00.25 top                                                                                                                                           
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                                                                                                                      
    3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 rcu_gp                                                                                                                                        
    4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 rcu_par_gp                                                                                                                                    
    6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H-kblockd                                                                                                                          
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.79 kworker/u24:0-events_unbound                                                                                                                  
    9 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq                                                                                                                                  
   10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.02 ksoftirqd/0                                                                                                                                   
   11 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:01.09 rcu_sched                                                                                                                                     
   12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.01 migration/0                                                                                                                                   
   13 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 idle_inject/0                                                                                                                                 
   14 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 cpuhp/0                                                                                                                                       
   15 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 cpuhp/1                                                                                                                                       
   16 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 idle_inject/1                                                                                                                                 
   17 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.02 migration/1                                                                                                                                   
   18 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.02 ksoftirqd/1                                                                                                                                   
   20 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0H-kblockd                                                                                                                          
   21 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 cpuhp/2                                                                                                                                       
   22 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 idle_inject/2                                                                                                                                 
   23 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.02 migration/2                                                                                                                                   
   24 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.01 ksoftirqd/2                                                                                                                                   
   26 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 kworker/2:0H-kblockd                                                                                                                          
   27 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 cpuhp/3                                                                                                                                       
   28 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 idle_inject/3                                                                                                                                 
   29 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.02 migration/3                                                                                                                                   
   30 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.01 ksoftirqd/3                                                                                                                                   
   32 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 kworker/3:0H-kblockd                                                                                                                          
   33 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 cpuhp/4
```

```
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          12
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-7
Off-line CPU(s) list:            8-11
Thread(s) per core:              1
Core(s) per socket:              6
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           158
Model name:                      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
Stepping:                        10
CPU MHz:                         1400.104
CPU max MHz:                     4100,0000
CPU min MHz:                     800,0000
BogoMIPS:                        4399.99
Virtualisation:                  VT-x
L1d cache:                       96 KiB
L1i cache:                       96 KiB
L2 cache:                        768 KiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-7
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     KVM: Mitigation: Split huge pages
Vulnerability L1tf:              Mitigation; PTE Inversion; VMX conditional cache flushes, SMT vulnerable
Vulnerability Mds:               Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Mitigation; PTI
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; Full generic retpoline, IBPB conditional, IBRS_FW, STIBP conditional, RSB filling
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
Flags:                           fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon
                                  pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcn
                                 t tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgs
                                 base tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_
                                 epp md_clear flush_l1d
```

EDIT 2:

```
 Time    User  Nice   Sys  Idle    IO  Run Ctxt/s  IRQ/s  Watts
11:22:36   0.4   0.0   0.1  98.1   1.5    1    803    737  18.12 
11:22:46   0.2   0.0   0.1  99.7   0.0    1    587    310  17.99 
11:22:56   0.3   0.0   0.1  98.9   0.7    1    680    346  17.93 
11:23:06   0.3   0.0   0.1  99.6   0.0    1    594    312  17.92 
11:23:16   0.3   0.0   0.1  99.5   0.1    1    658    349  17.89 
11:23:26   0.3   0.0   0.1  99.6   0.0    1    673    349  17.89 
11:23:36   0.3   0.0   0.2  99.5   0.0    1    675    361  17.89 
11:23:46   0.3   0.0   0.1  99.2   0.4    1    643    333  17.88 
11:23:56   0.3   0.0   0.2  99.5   0.0    1    663    342  17.87 
11:24:06   0.2   0.0   0.1  99.8   0.0    1    588    320  17.84 
11:24:16   0.3   0.0   0.1  99.4   0.2    1    666    352  17.85 
11:24:26   0.4   0.0   0.2  99.3   0.2    1    788    417  17.90 
11:24:36   0.4   0.0   0.1  99.3   0.1    1    706    390  17.88 
11:24:46   0.3   0.0   0.1  99.5   0.1    1    601    315  17.85 
11:24:56   0.3   0.0   0.1  99.4   0.2    1    692    364  17.88 
11:25:06   0.3   0.0   0.1  99.6   0.0    1    598    318  17.86 
11:25:16   0.3   0.0   0.1  99.6   0.0    1    684    370  17.86 
11:25:26   0.4   0.0   0.2  99.4   0.1    1    735    402  17.88 
11:25:36   0.3   0.0   0.1  99.5   0.1    1    674    368  17.88 
11:25:46   0.2   0.0   0.0  99.5   0.2    1    606    310  17.84 
11:25:56   0.4   0.0   0.1  99.4   0.1    2    667    355  17.87 
11:26:06   0.4   0.0   0.1  99.5   0.1    1    634    320  17.86 
  Time    User  Nice   Sys  Idle    IO  Run Ctxt/s  IRQ/s  Watts
11:26:16   0.4   0.0   0.1  99.5   0.1    1    652    342  17.86 
11:26:26   0.4   0.0   0.1  99.4   0.1    1    670    340  17.86 
11:26:36   0.6   0.0   0.3  99.0   0.1    1   1359   2139  18.00 
11:26:46   0.6   0.0   0.2  99.1   0.1    1   1125   1684  18.02 
11:26:56   0.3   0.0   0.1  99.4   0.2    1    600    313  17.95 
11:27:06   1.1   0.0   0.2  98.6   0.1    1    975    467  17.99 
11:27:16   0.3   0.0   0.2  99.5   0.1    1    669    334  17.93 
11:27:26   0.3   0.0   0.2  99.5   0.1    1    641    332  17.89 
11:27:36   0.4   0.0   0.2  99.3   0.1    1    898    986  17.95 
11:27:46   0.2   0.0   0.1  99.7   0.1    1    595    304  17.91 
11:27:56   0.4   0.0   0.1  99.4   0.1    1    661    335  17.89 
11:28:06   0.3   0.0   0.1  99.7   0.0    1    586    290  17.87 
11:28:16   0.4   0.0   0.1  99.4   0.0    1    665    345  17.87 
11:28:26   0.3   0.0   0.1  99.6   0.0    1    657    350  17.88 
11:28:36   0.4   0.0   0.2  99.1   0.4    1    690    367  17.89 
11:28:46   0.3   0.0   0.1  99.6   0.0    1    599    298  17.89 
11:28:56   0.5   0.0   0.2  99.0   0.4    2    665    358  17.89 
11:29:06   0.3   0.0   0.1  99.6   0.1    1    595    309  17.88 
11:29:16   0.4   0.0   0.1  99.4   0.1    1    667    349  17.89 
11:29:26   0.3   0.0   0.1  99.5   0.1    1    665    350  17.88 
11:29:36   0.3   0.0   0.1  99.4   0.2    1    680    372  17.89 
11:29:46   0.2   0.0   0.1  99.7   0.1    1    599    316  17.87 
  Time    User  Nice   Sys  Idle    IO  Run Ctxt/s  IRQ/s  Watts
11:29:56   0.4   0.0   0.1  99.5   0.0    1    644    337  17.88 
11:30:06   0.3   0.0   0.1  99.6   0.1    1    610    326  17.87 
11:30:16   0.4   0.0   0.2  99.4   0.0    1    644    341  17.88 
11:30:26   0.4   0.0   0.2  99.1   0.3    1    756    368  17.91 
-------- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ------ 
 Average   0.3   0.0   0.1  99.4   0.1  1.0  691.2  431.1  17.90 
 GeoMean   0.3   0.0   0.1  99.4   0.0  1.0  680.9  382.4  17.90 
  StdDev   0.1   0.0   0.0   0.3   0.2  0.2  138.8  331.3   0.05 
-------- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ------ 
 Minimum   0.2   0.0   0.0  98.1   0.0  1.0  585.8  290.4  17.84 
 Maximum   1.1   0.0   0.3  99.8   1.5  2.0 1358.6 2139.1  18.12 
-------- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ------ 
Summary:
System:  17.90 Watts on average with standard deviation 0.05
```

EDIT 3 (OSPower settings):
[Photo here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWOfg.jpg)

Comment: There are many "How to maximize your battery life while using Linux" articles out there. Are you just asking for us to provide a list of those links? Or are you asking how to troubleshoot energy-hogging processes so you can file a proper bug report? Or are you asking something else?

Comment: I migrated from Windows some years back, but I have been using Ubuntu since version 10.04, I have had both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 on my current laptop and I found that Windows run my battery down faster even with all of the power options fully optimised. What version of Ubuntu are you using?   Presumably you have optimised the power saving options in Ubuntu, like lowering the Screen Brightness, Dim Screen when Inactive, Blank Screen after n mins, Turn Off WIFI and Bluetooth to save power and Automatic Suspend when on battery power, setting the Night Light options?

Comment: I'm using 19.04, I've optimized all the promts you are saying but no difference. I even installed OSPower because TLP wasn't doing much more either, and it still feels the same. I've been looking up for links but they all recommend TLP or the turning-off-things solution. I also have dual boot with W10 but for some subjects I must use Windows because there are specific programs I can't use with Linux and Wine doesn't help sometimes

Comment: Ok perhaps you could run the top command from a terminal and post it to show all your running processes as suggested by @user535733 if its about energy hogging processes then this would be useful

Comment: In order that any potential answer providers have all the necessary information about your system, it would be helpful if you run the command lscpu in a terminal and attach the output of the command to your question, it would also be helpful to provide a screenshot of your current TLP/OSPower settings.

Comment: I've just edited the post with what you're asking for

Comment: Use powerstat -d 0 and let your machine idle. What power use? What graphics do you have? The number one reason for your problem is a badly configured NVIDIA card

Comment: PS I have a similar cpu. It idles at about 4w

Comment: Edited once again. It's a GTX 1050.

Comment: Could it be because of the dual boot? Some classmates are facing the same problem

Comment: Your high power use is almost certainly due to your NVIDIA card. sudo prime-select intel

Comment: After having typed the command, I have been using my laptop since then and it has definitely doubled or more its lifespan. Thank you very much!

Comment: As to extend @TimRichardson's comment, somehow opening Nvidia from Activities (results in an error if prime-select intel) decreases my power consumption.

Answer (score -3):

I believe a lot of it comes from the fact that snapd comsumes a lot of power as it mounts squashfs images for every single new program beyond the existing ones already installed, like: gnome-shell, gnome-calculator, gnome-characters and so on.

Each one of those programs have to be mounted. So, if your computer does not have enough "horse power" to handle all that, I suggest you may try to go raw with just apt packages by removing SNAPD. There is a post here on askubuntu that tells you how to do itsafelly.

Link:

[How can I safely remove snap without breaking apparmor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120452/how-can-i-safely-remove-snap-without-breaking-apparmor)

After you remove snapd the cycle consumption AND memory consumption goes down a fair bit.

If you remove it you will not have access to all snap channels and updates as they come, before new deb packages arrive.

Comment: I'll tell you tomorrow about this when I try it

Comment: This is not true. snapd is not your problem

Comment: Please edit your answer to link to a credible source for "*snapd consumes a lot of power as it mounts squashfs*."  I see no reports at snapcraft.io of snaps causing power hemorrhaging. The OP's `top` output does not seem to be showing any snaps in use.

Comment: You're right, after trying it nothing changed

Comment: My credible source is my experience with my machine, but there is no way to for me to show any proof as I also disabled cups, cups-browsed, fprintd, kerneloops, whoopsie and snapd, but there is more than one source here on askubuntu, even in the link to "howto remove snapd" that I have sent you, Don't get the me wrong I simply love both ubuntu and debian because I use it for a really long time

Comment: He does use snaps hw says he uses, but you use a fairly modern machine with irq balance, perhaps  this ccan help : https://serverfault.com/questions/513807/is-there-still-a-use-for-irqbalance-on-modern-hardware

Comment: Irqbalance and virtual machines on modern hardware.